# Focus leave text box

Tags: c#

I have a text box `TB` and a handler `EH` for the event Focus / Leave.

Also, I have a button `BT` to quit the program when clicked, only dispose();
If I leave `TB` box without proper data in it, the focus leave event handler is triggered to check the data, it warns me and return focus back to `TB`.

But if I want to quit the program while `TB` has the focus and click `BT`, again the `EH` is triggered and returns the focus to `TB` and the program won't quit.

How can I solve this matter?  Here's the code :

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void EH(object sender, EventArgs e) // event handler EH
{
    double temp;
    if (TB.Text == "")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Must enter a valid distance for d1!\r\n" +
            "The valid range is ( 10,32 )",
            "Wake up!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            TB.Focus();
            return;
    }
    else
    try
    {
        temp = Convert.ToDouble(TB.Text);
        if (temp < 10 || temp > 32)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid distance for d1!\r\n" +
            "The valid range is ( 10,32 )",
            "Again! Wake up!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                TB.Text = "";
                TB.Focus();
                return;
        }
        minh1 = 1 / 8 * temp; // sets minimum h1
            if (minh1 < 10)
                minh1 = 10;
    }
    catch (Exception) // can't convert
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid numeric entry!\r\n" +
        "Please enter a valid number!",
        "Hey! Wake up!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
         TB.Text = "";
         TB.Focus();
    }
}

private void TB_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) // change text in TB
{
    if (TB.Text == "")
        btgo.Enabled = false;
    else
        btgo.Enabled = true;
}
private void btgo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // Execute!
{
    say.Text = "Minimum height h1 has been calculated to be " +
    string.Format("{0:#0.00}", minh1) + " Fts";
    BT.Focus();
}
private void BT_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // --- PROGRAM END ---
{
    Dispose();
}
```

Comment: How do you bind the EH event to the control?

Comment: Winforms already wraps this pretty well, the need is common.  It has a Validating event, designed to let you complain.  And controls have a CausesValidation property, allowing you to click a button without triggering a Validating event.  The ValidateChildren method runs when you close the form.  Use the force Luke.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to create a global field to store permission for the program to exit,like this;

```
bool Quit=false;
```

Now when you've done some checks whether to exit the program,you can set this variable to `true` or `false` in case something is left.From now onwards whenever the `BT_Click` event is fired(the Exit event) set this variable to true,like this;

```
private void BT_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //--- PROGRAM END ---
{
    Quit = true;//Flag to exit the program.
    Dispose();
}
```

When you've don this add this code at the very beginning of `EH`;

```
private void EH(object sender, EventArgs e) // event handler EH
{
 if(Quit)//If Quit is true,means exit the program.
 {
   return;//No processing,just return.
 }
   //Run regular logic,if the function doesn't need to return.
}
```

But to make sure that the logic in `EH` runs,set `Quit` to `false` in the `TextChangedEvent`,like this;

```
private void TB_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) // change text in TB
{
Quit=false;//Set this to false to make sure `EH` event's code is executed.
if (TB.Text == "")
    btgo.Enabled = false;
else
    btgo.Enabled = true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried some like this, also tried to set a tag to the BT and make EH to check the tag but the result is just the same, the program won't quit... have you tried the code? any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Keep an indicator that states whether an exit request was made.

```
private bool _isQuitRequested = false;
```

In the BT click event add

```
private void BT_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // --- PROGRAM END ---
{
    _isQuitRequested = true;
    Dispose();
}
```

In the begining of the event handler `EH` add

```
if (_isQuitRequested) return;
```

Don't forget to change `_isQuitRequest` back to false in `TB_TextChanged`